# Dynamic table names within MYSQL statement (Google Cloud SQL)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to drop/delete a table from within Google Cloud SQL using Python (App Engine) but I want the table name to be based on a variable, for simplicity I am using 'hello' here. For some reason it is throwing back an error at me: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-IN' at line 1"

I tried the following:

```
tabNameShort = 'hello'    
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s', (tabNameShort))
conn.commit()
```

I also tried:

```
tabNameShort = 'hello'    
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + tabNameShort)
conn.commit()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: My mistake - the real variable had a special character in it (a hyphen just before IN), so that explains the SQL Syntax Error. Apologies.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, only version II would work - first example doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tabNameShort = 'hello'    
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `%s`' % tabNameShort)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

A warning: appending the table name directly using '+' can result in an SQL injection vulnerability, if the table name is derived, directly or indirectly, from user input.